# Keras: setting an array element with a sequence error

Tags: keras, lstm

I try to build a very simple LSTM to classify text.

```python
def encoded(texts):
  res = [one_hot(text, 100000, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', split=' ') for text in texts]
  return res

def train(X, y, X_t, y_t):
  X = encoded(X)
  X_t = encoded(X_t)   

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Embedding(100000,100))
  model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20,return_sequences = True),merge_mode='ave'))
  model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y), batch_size=16, epochs=8)

  score = model.evaluate(np.array(X_t), np.array(y_t), batch_size = 16)
  print(score)
```

However I got this error:

**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

It seems like embedding layer didnt create right dimension vector or something wrong with the format of input X(X_t).

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the trace of the error so we know exactly where it's happening?

Comment: Error in this line: model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y), batch_size=16, epochs=8)